# Subquery implementation

Tags: sqlite, date, request, subquery, where-clause

I have a table `employees`

```
------------------------------------------------
| name  | email              | date_employment |
|-------+--------------------|-----------------|
| MAX   | qwerty@gmail.com   | 2021-08-18      |
| ALEX  | qwerty2@gmail.com  | 1998-07-10      |
| ROBERT| qwerty3@gmail.com  | 2016-08-23      |
| JOHN  | qwerty4@gmail.com  | 2001-03-09      |
------------------------------------------------
```

and I want to write a subquery that will display employees who have been with them for more than 10 years.

```
SELECT employees.name, employees.email, employees.date_employment
FROM employees
WHERE 10 > (SELECT round((julianday('now') - julianday(employees.date_employment)) / 365, 0) FROM employees);
```

After executing this request, it displays all employees, regardless of their seniority.
If you write a request like this, then everything works

```
SELECT name, round((julianday('now') - julianday(employees.date_employment)) / 365, 0) as ex
FROM employees WHERE ex > 10;
```

Why subquery  is not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the subquery:

```
SELECT round((julianday('now') - julianday(employees.date_employment)) / 365, 0) AS ex
FROM employees
```

you will see that it returns 4 rows:

| ex |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 24 |
| 6 |
| 21 |

It does not make sense to use the above resultset in a condition of a `WHERE` clause to compare it with 10.
But SQLite allows it, while other databases would throw an error.

How does SQLite handle this case?
It choses only 1 value of the resultset (usually the *first*) and uses it in the `WHERE` clause, so your code is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 10 > 1
```

which is always `true` and this is why you get all the rows of the table as a result.

Comment: well, show me how I can see employees with more than 10 years of experience?

Comment: @arnold you already have the solution. Use your last query.